# appending to a list of objects within a dictionary of objects in python

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

I am creating a class that has a list of a second object and a total of the amount value from the second object. This in itself works. However I need to group them by category so I created a dictionary of them. Which seems simple however whenever I append an object to a list it appends to all of the lists in the dictionary.

```
class objA:
    amount = 0
    listBs = []
    category = ""
    def __init__(self,category):
        self.category = category
class objB:
    amount = 0
    category = ""
    otherproperty = ""

mydict = {}

b1 = objB()
b1.amount = 1
b1.category = "foo"
b1.otherproperty = "abc"

if(b1.category not in mydict.keys()):
    mydict[b1.category] = objA(b1.category)
mydict[b1.category].listBs.append(b1)
mydict[b1.category].amount += b1.amount


b2 = objB()
b2.amount = 2
b2.category = "bar"
b2.otherproperty = "xyz"

if(b2.category not in mydict.keys()):
    mydict[b2.category] = objA(b2.category)
mydict[b2.category].listBs.append(b2)
mydict[b2.category].amount += b2.amount

print("foo amount: " + str(mydict["foo"].amount) + " - foo len: " + str(len(mydict["foo"].listBs)))
print("bar amount: " + str(mydict["bar"].amount) + " - bar len: " + str(len(mydict["bar"].listBs)))
```

when I run the above code I get the expected amount of 1 for foo and 2 for bar but both lists have a len of 2 since they both contain b1 and b2.

I took the class objects out and the same pricipal works just appending to a dict of lists so the following works

```
dictoflists = {}
dictoflists["key1"] = []
dictoflists["key1"].append("k1v1")
dictoflists["key2"] = []
dictoflists["key2"].append("k2v1")
dictoflists["key2"].append("k2v2")
print(dictoflists)
```

output:

```
{'key1': ['k1v1'], 'key2': ['k2v1', 'k2v2']}
```

Is there a way to get this to work or a better solution?

Comment: `objA.listBs` has been defined on the class itself. Every time you reference `listBs` from any instance of `objA` it will be a reference to the same list

Comment: @IainShelvington How do I achieve the desired behavior giving each instance of objA it's own listBs? Is there some other way to define it that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of the `objA` class so that the variables are defined pre-instance instead of on the class itself

```
class objA:
    def __init__(self, category):
        self.category = category
        self.amount = 0
        self.listBs = []
```

Comment: I just realized I forgot to mark this as the correct answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have initialized the variable inside constructor -

```
class objA:
        amount = 0

        category = ""
        def __init__(self,category):
            self.category = category
      #Initialize the variable inside constructor     
            self.listBs = []
class objB:
    amount = 0
    category = ""
    otherproperty = ""

mydict = {}

b1 = objB()
b1.amount = 1
b1.category = "foo"
b1.otherproperty = "abc"

if(b1.category not in mydict.keys()):
    mydict[b1.category] = objA(b1.category)
mydict[b1.category].listBs.append(b1)
mydict[b1.category].amount += b1.amount


b2 = objB()
b2.amount = 2
b2.category = "bar"
b2.otherproperty = "xyz"

if(b2.category not in mydict.keys()):
    mydict[b2.category] = objA(b2.category)
mydict[b2.category].listBs.append(b2)
mydict[b2.category].amount += b2.amount

print("foo amount: " + str(mydict["foo"].amount) + " - foo len: " + str(len(mydict["foo"].listBs)))
print("bar amount: " + str(mydict["bar"].amount) + " - bar len: " + str(len(mydict["bar"].listBs)))
```